# Ajax error: failed to bind request element

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

When my ajax request runs, I get this error:

> WARN  DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:361 - Failed to bind request
>   element:
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
>   Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   For input string: "getDateTimeFormat
>
> Ajax error: 400:Bad Request - /dobi/activity/activityEntry/edit/getDateTimeFormat

My controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDateTimeFormat")
public Boolean getDateTimeFormat(HttpSession session) {

    Boolean status = Boolean.FALSE;

    return status;
}
```

My ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/dobi/activity/activityEntry/edit/getDateTimeFormat",
  cache: true,
  success: function (response) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

Also, I'm using `cache: true` because it was appending unwanted data in the url request.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess. Have not tried the code.

Your method's return type is Boolean, whereas your return values are primitive boolean.

You need to [box it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

Update:

Proper usage should be:

```
Boolean status = Boolean.FALSE;
```

Comment: Ok. So I just changed the declaration to `Boolean status = false`. It still shows the same errors

Comment: I updated my answer above but I am not sure if it fixes the problem. It just got my attention and I thought there is no harm to give it a try.

Comment: I updated the code as you mentioned. Boolean.FALSE and Boolean.True. It didn't fix it :/

Comment: can you share how you implemented Department getCurrentDepartnment(session) method?

Comment: Ok. So I updated the code. removed all the crap for simplicity and ran it. It still shows the same errors.

Comment: I changed the datatype to int just to experiment and returned 1. It still says that it cannot convert it to Long. Where is that Long and String the error is talking about?